# Is $L^p(\Omega) = L^p(\bar {\Omega})$?

Tags: proof-verification, lebesgue-measure

Is it true that $L^p(\Omega) = L^p(\bar {\Omega})$, where let us say $\Omega$ is a bounded domain of $\mathbb{R}^n$ with smooth boundary? I think it is true, because $\partial \bar {\Omega}$ has measure zero. Am I correct?

Comment: I think also. If $f \in L^p(\overline \Omega)$ of course $f$ restricts to $L^p(\Omega)$. Conversely, we can choose a representant which is $0$ on $\partial \Omega$. It's a smooth manifold of dimension $n-1$, in particular of measure zero. (Unless I miss something...)

Comment: @N.H. sorry. I missed the smooth manifold part. You are right.